# How can I keep consistent line height with superscript elements?

Tags: html, css, subscript, superscript

If I have a `<sup>` element in a multi-line paragraph, the line with the superscript on it has a larger line spacing above it than the other lines, regardless of what line-height I put on the paragraph.

It doesn't mean I have lots of paragraphs, each which is on a single line. I have a single paragraph with enough content in it to cause wrapping onto multiple lines. Somewhere (anywhere) in the text there may be a `<sup>` or `<sub>`. This affects the line height for that line by adding extra spacing above/below. If I set a larger line-height on the paragraph this makes no difference to the problem. The line-height is increased, but the extra spacing still remains.

How can I make it consistent - i.e. all lines have the same spacing whether they contain a `<sup>` or not?

Your solutions must be cross-browser (IE 6+, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome)

Answer (score 204, accepted):

line-height does fix it, but you might have to make it pretty large: on my setttings I have to increase line-height to about 1.8 before the `<sup>` no longer interferes with it, but this will vary from font to font.

One possible approach to get consistent line heights is to set your own superscript styling instead of the default `vertical-align: super`. If you use `top` it won't add anything to the line box, but you may have to reduce font size further to make it fit:

```
sup { vertical-align: top; font-size: 0.6em; }
```

Another hack you could try is to use positioning to move it up a bit without affecting the line box:

```
sup { vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: -0.5em; }
```

Of course this runs the risk of crashing into the line above if you don't have enough line-height.

Comment: vertical-align fixed it, thanks. Even a massive line-height 300%+ does not fix it in IE8, Chrome 3 or FF 3.5. I still get 1-2px of difference.

Comment: As mentioned this doesn't always work if the line height is too tight.

Comment: @simPod: Same situation, `vertical-align: bottom` (though that doesn't get you as much as `top`) and then `position:relative;` with a positive `top`.

Comment: actually I'd prefer {vertical-align: super} because it prevents some display glitches with line-height in IE8 as far as I remember. I would try not to use positioning to often if there are better alternatives. Careless top positioning might result in cascaded problems later in the project.

Comment: font-size : 0.75em

Comment: this second option fixed it for me. I was running into same issues as OP. what's weird is I also had to change the vertical-align value from 'super' to 'top'. seems like the 'super' value should have this as part of it's value

Answer (score 130):

```
sup {
    line-height: 0;

    /* The following rules (or similar) likely come from browser 
     * style and are not needed
     */
    font-size: 0.83em;
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

The trick is to set the `<sup>`'s line-height to 0. @Scott said to use normal, but this doesn't always work.

This means you **don't have to change** the line-height of surrounding text to accommodate the superscript text. I've tested this in IE7+ and the other major browsers.

Comment: +1. As noted, this prevents conflicts with the other `line-height` attributes. It can still cause intersections with the previous line if the overall `line-height` is set to small, of course.

Comment: fantastic solution, makes chromium not misbehave anymore! The simplest answer yet.

Comment: Just realized that this will affect non-default line-heights of the surrounding text. Use `line-height: 100%` in this case.

Comment: This works perfectly. Additionally, possible values for `line-height` I have found to be 0, 1, 1em & 100%. All of these certainly work in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: I also prefer this answer for my use case: This answer works on emails in Gmail, the accepted answer does not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118072/gmail-removes-positionrelative-as-inline-css-email-temlate

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and non of the given answers worked. But I found a [git commit](https://gist.github.com/unruthless/413930) with a fix that did work for me:

```
sup {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  top: -0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**keep it easy:**

```
sup { vertical-align: text-top; }
```

[*font-size* dependent on your individual type-face]

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the solution suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-superscripts-and-subscripts-from-affecting-line-height/), as exemplified by [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exkbwv3d/1/):

CSS:

```
sup, sub {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.2em;
}

sub {
  top: 0.2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span>The following equation is perhaps the most well known of all: </span><span id="box">E<sub>a</sub> = mc<sup>2</sup></span><span>.  And it gives an opportunity to try out a superscript and even throw in a superfluous subscript!  I'm sure that Einstein would be pleased.</span>.
```

The beauty of this solution is that you can tailor the vertical positioning of the superscript and subscript, to avoid any clashes with the line above or below... in the above, just increase or decrease the `0.2em` to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
sup, sub {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}
sub { 
  top: 0.4em; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

I only needed to change the default <sup> behavior in one section of the page, so I applied a class there.  Also for me vertical-align: top worked just fine, goosed up about 4 pixels.

```
sup.my-class {
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the `<sup>` tag is affecting the spacing between two lines has to do with a number of factors. The factors are: line height, size of the superscript in relation to the regular font, the line height of the superscript and last but not least what is the bottom of the superscript aligning with...
If you set... the line height of regular text to be in a "tunnel band" (that's what I call it) of 135% then regular text (the 100%) gets white padded by 35% of more white. For a paragraph this looks like this:

```
 p
    {
            line-height: 135%;
    }
```

If you then do not white pad the superscript...(i.e. keep its line height to 0) the superscript only has the width of its own text... if you then ask the superscript to be a percentage of the regular font (for example 70%) and you align it with the middle of the regular text (text-middle), you can eliminate the problem and get a superscript that looks like a superscript. Here it is:

```
sup
{
    font-size: 70%;
    vertical-align: text-middle;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `length` on the vertical-align. This aligns the baseline of the element at the given length above the baseline of its parent.

```
sup {
   font-size: .83em;
   vertical-align: 0.25em;
   line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make all lines *taller*, to look the same as the line with the superscript, define a larger `line-height` for the entire paragraph

```
<p style='line-height:150%'>
```

or whatever value gives the effect you desire.

It may look strange, but that's how you described your requirements.

EDIT: In order to make all lines look the same *when only one needs more vertical space than the others*, ALL lines in the paragraph will have to be taller.

This, as I said, may not an attractive solution. Maybe something can be done with a span making just the text with the sub/superscript *smaller*, apart from that I don't believe what you want can be achieved. But I'd like to see someone else's solution.

EDIT2: Incidentally, I've tried a small html file containing

```
<html>
<head>
<title>line-height</title>
<style>
p {
    line-height : 1.5em;
    width : 25em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Mary had a little lamb, its fleece<sup>1</sup> was white as snow, 
and everywhere that Mary went, the lamb<sub>2</sub> was sure to go.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the lines are all the same height in FF3.0.14 and Konqueror (I can't speak for other browsers)

Comment: i said in the question that this doesnt solve the problem. Ive added clarification incase you misunderstood

Comment: yeah I understand if i need more room for one line, for consistency i need to add extra room to the others, thats obvious. What i'm saying is line-height doesnt fix it, this increases the space yes, but there is _still extra_ space with the sup

Comment: Maybe there's a difference between browsers - after all, the answer you accepted begins 'line-height does fix it', but we don't know what browser bobince was using.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using line-height: normal for the superscript, which works fine for me in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, but I'm not sure about IE.

Answer (score 0):

Specially use this on newsletter -

```
<sup style="font-size:9px; line-height:8px;">&reg;</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Milingu Kilu's solution but in the same spirit I prefer

```
sup { vertical-align:top; line-height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

&sup1, &sup2 etc. might do the trick. it's an HTML trick to superscript

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [here](http://blog.emailwizardry.co/2012/12/how-to-fix-superscript-characters/), works in both phantomjs and in email-embedded HTML:

```html
Lorem ipsum <sup style="font-size: 8px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 3px">&reg;</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I have working:

```
<div>
 <span>line</span><br/>
 <span>span styled with vertical align super</span><span style="vertical-align:super;">1</span><br/>
 <span>line</span><br/>
 <span>same as before but line height set to 0</span><span style="vertical-align:super; line-height:0; font-size:.75em">1</span><br/>
 <span>line</span><br/>
 <span>now using sup tag and sup class with line height 0</span><sup style="line-height: 0">1</sup><br/>
 <span>line</span>
</div>
```