# How to get cross browser <sup> without intrerupting line height?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

How to get cross browser `<sup>` without interrupting line height?

I tried `vertical-align:top` but it looks ok in FF 3.6 and IE but not in FF 3.0.

How to get consistent in size (size of superlative text) and position of `<sup>` identical in all browsers without interrupting line height.

I'm using `<sup>` to indicate footnote? not to show power

```
<p> Stackoverflow is killing<sup>10</sup> experts-exchange</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530685/html-sup-tag-affecting-line-height-how-to-make-it-consistent) question. The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6594576/564181) resolves the problem nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Your best chance for a consistent rendering are real superscripts:

**HTML**

```
<p>Stackoverflow is killing<span class="unicode">¹⁰</span> experts-exchange</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.unicode
{
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Arial Unicode MS';
}
```

**Live**

> Stackoverflow is killing¹⁰ experts-exchange

Comment: Just use real superscript numbers. The CSS is helping browsers to find a font with these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can take it a bit further..

```
sup{
    height: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    _vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align: text-top;
```