# Need raised MC character in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I need to show a raised MC character in my jsp
My jsp has a paragraph, which has postelMC, but the MC should be raised.

I tried `<sup>MC</sup>` , but this doesn't work in safari and chrome, only works in IE, FIREFOX

I also tried using unicode in jsp \uD83C\uDD6A and adding `<%@ page language="java" charset=UTF-8" %>` on top of jsp page. But this doesn't work either.

any help is greatly appreciated. i need it for a production fix.

My paragraph in jsp is

```
<p class="ePostCopyText">Tous les messages de votre boîte aux lettres postelMC figurent
```

Comment: The sup tag definitely works in Chrome, can you get an example e.g. jsfiddle ?

Comment: my qa team told me it doesn't. Although they showed me the bug in safari. It definetely doesn't work in safari. that's bad enough. is there any alternative. jsfiddle .. i am not sure i understood.

Comment: Does this question help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530685/html-sup-tag-affecting-line-height-how-to-make-it-consistent

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML character as suggested at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f16a/index.htm

```
&#127338;
```