# Gmail removes "position:relative" as inline CSS (Email Template)

Tags: css, email, html-email

From what I understand Gmail doesn't accept CSS blocks in the head at all, which is why I have been adding a bunch of inline CSS to my email template to make it work.

However, I'm struggling with the CSS positioning property. I want an image to sit on top of a background image so I set the parent div of both to `position: relative` and the image to absolute. However, for some reason Gmail removes the style attribute that declares the position: relative from the div. It keeps all other inline CSS though.

Any idea? Any workaround?

Comment: CSS `position` is not well supported in html email. For background images, you should take a look at backgrounds.cm. You could then place a normal image tag within the inner `<td>`.

Comment: Tools like MJML don’t solve this problem (that exists years later!) but do help a lot building emails.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sadly, I suspect you may have to abandon your perfectly reasonable ideas of divs and positioning when designing for email. CSS support in email clients is a tangled nightmare.

The only (relatively) surefire way of forcing layout on email is to go with an old school tables layout, which is unfortunate, but unavoidable.

Campaign Monitor has an excellent summary of email client CSS support [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: As much as it sucks, nested tables are the only way to go in regards to creating HTML newsletters. Advanced CSS is also out of the question.

Comment: Thanks both! I worked with tables now, added a background image to the td tag and places my overlay image within the table data. Not pretty, but it works! :)

Answer (score 5):

I experienced similar layout problems when sending email newsletters. The solution was to use tables to position things properly. It's dated, but I think it was the only way to make things look the way they should.