# Why is the text not centered when sent in a mail?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I have a normal html code.

```html
<span style="bottom: 65px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px; color: red;">Hiii</span>
    <img   src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/sqmegapolis/images/2/2d/RealWorld_Stonehenge.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150616102050">
```

When I run this code, the text is centered.

But when I send this code to gmail, the look changes.
In gmail looks like

[image: this]

Here the text is not centered and when I inspected it I also found that all the css is not passed to gmail.

[image: Here]

This CSS is not passed:

```
bottom: 65px;
position: relative;
left: 100px;
```

I need the text to always be centered whenever I send this html body to gmail/mail.

Comment: Which Service are you using for sending HTML body to Gmail?

Comment: I am using sendgrid

Comment: ok, then use a table in which `Hi`  will be your header Text and image will be a row.
I hope this helps.

Comment: can you please write the code?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Tables for email. But as a quick fix for you, `div` will make it.

```html
<div style="width:600px;">
<div style="text-align: center; color: #ff0000;">
  Hello World. I'm in the center :)
</div>
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/sqmegapolis/images/2/2d/RealWorld_Stonehenge.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150616102050" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

With tables (all centered):

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            Hello World. I&#39;m in the center :)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/sqmegapolis/images/2/2d/RealWorld_Stonehenge.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150616102050" style="width: 100%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want always text have to come at the center of image.
It is not what i expected

Comment: I've updated code snippet. 
If you need to center the whole thing, then I'm including brief table approach.
hope this helps :)

P.S. Pick your width and other styles ;)

Comment: can you add the text in the center of image.
I need the hi text in the center of image.
Image can  be left or right. My point is whatever the position of image is there I always need Hii text comes to center of image'

Comment: the only thing I can recommend from this point is to try playing with background images. Email development is pretty limited thing.
_E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118072/gmail-removes-positionrelative-as-inline-css-email-temlate_