# Inline Positioning in Email Template

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, inline

Can anyone help me find an alternative way to create the below functionality in an email template. [Inline position styling is being removed from the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118072/gmail-removes-positionrelative-as-inline-css-email-temlate).

```css
table {
   width: 80%;
   border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr td.label-dots {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

table tr td.label-dots span {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table tr td:not(.label-dots) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tr>
    
        <td class="label-dots">Label<span>...................................................................................................................</span></td>
        <td>$9.99</td>
        
    </tr>

</table>
```

[image: screenshot of the desired bottom border effect]

Comment: I would ditch the dots (or dashes) proceeding to the dollar amount (like @gwally has done). Maintenance will be a nightmare and it will render different in different devices.

Answer (score 1):

This works in every email client:

`border: 1px dotted #000000;`

Example:

```html
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="400" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
   <td width="50">Item</td>
   <td width="300" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
   <td width="50">Price</td>
  </tr>
</table>    
<table>
```