# Align image that's in same line as text in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates

So I've scoured this website to try and fix my issue but **nothing** has fixed it. I even tried putting it in a superscript tag as Outlook has weird hacks that you would think wouldn't work but they do sometimes. I need a small image to align as follows in Outlook:

[image]

Unfortunately, Outlook isn't playing nice and aligns the image like this. If you run the code in a browser, it looks fine of course. But not Outlook:

[image]

Here is my code. The class for this table is for mobile only and merely adjusts the percentage of the table:

```html
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#E6F1FF" style="color: #323840; padding: 10px 5px 40px 0px; margin: 0;" class="intmed">

    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="68%" class="support">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="font-family:'Inter-Medium', 'Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-size: 14px;
                            font-weight: 500; letter-spacing: -0.22px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center;">
          <span>For any support needs, please use the in-app help feature by clicking the &nbsp;</span>
          <span style="height: 16px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">        
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16" height="16" width="16" 
                                style="vertical-align: bottom;">     
                                </span>
          <span>&nbsp; in the bottom corner of your screen or reach
                               out to <a href="mailto:" target="_blank" style="color:#1e61ac;
                                    text-decoration: underline; text-underline-offset: 1.5px; font-family: 'Inter-Bold', 'Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" class="bld">
                                   <strong style="color:#1e61ac; font-weight: bold;">someemail@email.com</strong></a></span>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>


  </td>
</tr>
```

Since this is Outlook (Office 365 specifically), there are many tags that cannot be used such as float, negative margins, display: flex, etc and I have to code like it's 1999 with horrible tables. I cannot change any style element of the text surrounding it and I have to use this image.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does `position:relative` work? it's a classic from 1999

Comment: @ITgoldman why should it not work? It is still used and a W3C-specified property which up to now has not been deprecated (and properly never will).

Comment: Top does NOT work in Outlook @ITgoldman and neither do negative values. See this link
https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=top

Comment: That's too bad. Indeed according to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118072/gmail-removes-positionrelative-as-inline-css-email-template), `<table>` is the way to do HTML for emails.

Comment: Yes I know which is why I have it laid out in a table. New Outlook at the end of the year may finally mean the end of tables, though.
Please let me know if you can think of any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to try.

I'm not sure if making a table around the image would work, i.e.:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 role=presentation><tr><td style="margin-top:5px"><img ...></td></tr></table>
```

Perhaps easiest would be to add the required padding to the image itself.

Another option is to use an Outlook-specific hack, first used in a button, so not sure if that would work in this context:

```
<!--[if mso]><i style="letter-spacing: 25px;mso-font-width:-100%;mso-text-raise:30pt" hidden>&nbsp;</i><![endif]-->
```

You would put that before the `<img ...>` tag.

It has to do with line-height (and perhaps font-size), so you can also play around with that, e.g. in the span around the image.