# How to format a superscript with HTML

Tags: html, web

[image: The text Kasparov and 1 written somewhat above to it]

How do I format this in a HTML page? What is the tag for it? I don’t know how to get this 1 written above the text.

Comment: POssible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530685/html-sup-tag-affecting-line-height-how-to-make-it-consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `<sup>` element for *superscript* text.

Like<sup>this</sup>.

```
<p>Like<sup>this</sup></p>
```

There's also `<sub>` for subscript text:

Like<sub>this</sub>.

```
<p>Like<sub>this</sub></p>
```

Note that these elements are meant for actual textual superscript and subscript text. Remember that HTML is semantic: it describes what the content is, not what the content looks like (that's what CSS is for).

In CSS you can do this the simple way by setting `vertical-align: super` with `font-size: 80%` on an *inline-element* (like `<span>` but not `<div>`, a *block-element*).

Another approach is to do it manually with creative use of `margin` or `position: relative` - in which case it depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [SuperScript tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)

```
Kasparov<sup>1</sup>
```

Kasparov<sup>1</sup>